ADB SU root inputs location
Simply, where do I enter the commands for SU abilities and root access or settings?   No, I'm not doing this for any reason and I don't need to throw an explanation at all. I'm just tooling around and I'm trying to learn on my own as well as reading and doing my own research, so please spare me the why, the what's, and the who's and just explain to me where I enter these commands. See the picture below please thank you.
Just an example, but the line /system..etc...

Source: Can android user become a super user in android?
fd = open("/system/file.txt", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0) {
        return -8002;
    }

This is very important for us. I shall be very thankful to all who will help me with this.

Where in my Android do I enter commands like that?

Note that the code you have quoted from the other question is C code (wich needs to be compiled and is part of a larger program). And it has nothing to do with becoming or using root permissions, it is simply a command that opens a file on the system partition in read/write mode. IMHO instead of quoting other questions you should describe what you are trying to do and what you have already tried.

If you have an Android device that is rooted with ADB enabled, you can access the root environment like this:
adb shell su root whoami
This should respond:
root
The breakdown of this command is:

adb Run the ADB program on your computer. For this example, it doesn't matter what OS your computer is running provided you have the adb program available via PATH.
shell Run the "shell", the command-line interpreter, on the device.
su Run the su program on the device.
root Tell su that you want to use the root account and its privileges.
whoami Tell su to run the whoami program, which just prints the name of the account that has run it. You can use other programs in place of whoami, it was just a convenient example for this answer.

If none of this answer meant much to you, you need to learn about using computers from their command lines. That idea is not Android-specific, and it's easier to learn it on a Windows, Linux or macOS machine. All of these have somewhat different command line systems, but the basic idea is the same on all of them. The Android command line system is a variant on the Linux one.
